# I can't install django through pip

Tags: python, django

Im trying to install django on an venv using python (3.9) on vsc.
I already had a hard time activating the venv and now i can't seem to be able to install django.

when i use pip install django this shows up :
(env) PS C:\CODE_PROJECTS\django_test> pip install Django
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\camil\CODE_PROJECTS\django_test\env\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\CODE_PROJECTS\django_test\env\Scripts\pip3.9.exe" install Django': O sistema nÒo pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

I have tried pip3, pip3.9 also and same result
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

First try to update the pip

```
 python -m pip install -U pip
```

Open a new env with

```
python -m venv Env
```

Activate the Env in windows - cmd

```
Env\Scripts\activate
```

Install Django

```
python -m pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try pipwin django! maybe that'd work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).